# Populating a vector with known number of elements: specify its size in constructor or by using reserve method?

Tags: c++, vector, std

I would like to create a vector of some complex type, by reading individual elements from a stream. I know the vector size in advance. Is it better to specify the number of elements in the vector constructor or by using reserve method? Which one of these two is better?

```
int myElementCount = stream.ReadInt();
vector<MyElement> myVector(myElementCount);
for (int i = 0; i < myElementCount; i++)
{
    myVector[i] = stream.ReadMyElement();
}
```

or

```
int myElementCount = stream.ReadInt();
vector<MyElement> myVector;
myVector.reserve(myElementCount);
for (int i = 0; i < myElementCount; i++)
{
    myVector.push_back(stream.ReadMyElement());
}
```

What about the case where I just create a vector of ints or some other simple type.

Comment: Use `resize()` instead of `reserve()`, it's a common confusion for newbs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why? Doesn't `resize` also default construct the objects? OP is doing the `push_back` anyway. Maybe I'm confused too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what `MyElement` is, especially what its `operator=` does, so it's largely the usual "try both and use the faster one for you". There is a third choice, use c++11 and `emplace_back`, especially if `MyElement` is heavy.

As a datapoint, for `int` or `double` I found that using the constructor (or `resize()`) and `[]` is faster. Specifically, this way the loop is much easier for the compiler to vectorize.

Comment: Side comment: `emplace_back` and `push_back` are equivalent on rvalues (which is what the OP is using), the latter also moves the object. But I agree that `emplace_back` clearly states the intention.

Comment: *"especially what its `operator=` does"* - the `push_back` approach involves (possibly elided) copy construction of elements (with the default allocator, that's basically a placement new), while the constructor-sized approach involve default construction then assignment, so the relative costs of all those operations is important, as is whether the compiler can optimise away repeated capacity checks and size increments effectively then do as much loop unrolling or other optimisations....